# How can I take multiple vectors and recode their datatypes in R?

Tags: r, statistics

#### I'm looking for an elegant way to change multiple vectors' datatypes in R.

I'm working with an educational dataset: 426 students' answers to eight multiple choice questions (`1` = correct, `0` = incorrect), plus a column indicating which instructor (`1, 2, or 3`) taught their course.

As it stands, my data is sitting pretty in `data.df`, like this:

```
    str(data.df)
    'data.frame': 426 obs. of  9 variables:
    $ ques01: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 ...
    $ ques02: int  0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
    $ ques03: int  0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 ...
    $ ques04: int  1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
    $ ques05: int  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
    $ ques06: int  1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 ...
    $ ques07: int  0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 ...
    $ ques08: int  0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 ...
    $ inst  : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

But those `ques0x` values aren't **really** integers. Rather, I think it's better to have R treat them as experimental factors. Same goes for the "inst" values.

#### I'd love to turn all those `int`s and `num`s into `factors`

Ideally, an elegant solution should produce a dataframe—I call it `factorData.df`—that looks like this:

```
    str(factorData.df)
    'data.frame': 426 obs. of  9 variables:
    $ ques01: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 ...
    $ ques02: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
    $ ques03: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 2 ...
    $ ques04: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
    $ ques05: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
    $ ques06: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
    $ ques07: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 ...
    $ ques08: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 ...
    $ inst  : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

I'm fairly certain that whatever solution you folks come up with, it ought to be easy to generalize to any n number of variables that'd need to get reclassified, and would work across most common conversions (`int -> factor` and `num -> int`, for example).

#### No matter what solution you folks generate, it's **bound** to be more elegant than mine

Because my current clunky code is just 9 separate `factor()` statements, one for each variable, like this

```
    factorData.df$ques01
```

I'm brand-new to R, programming, and stackoverflow. Please be gentle, and thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: @briandk: Since the questions can only be correct or incorrect, you might be better converting columns 1-8 to logical vectors rather than factors.  (Factors would be appropriate for, say, the answers to multiple choice questions, where there are more than 2 possibilities.)

Comment: @Richie: thanks for the suggestion! I'm not familiar with logical datatypes in vectors. If they are a datatype just like nums, ints, and factors, then would your suggestion be to just use lapply to turn columns 1-8 into logical factors?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This was also answered in R-Help.](http://www.nabble.com/Apply-as.factor-(or-as.numeric-etc)-to-multiple-columns-td24174823.html)

I imagine that there's a better way to do it, but here are two options:

```
# use a sample data set
> str(cars)
'data.frame':   50 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ speed: num  4 4 7 7 8 9 10 10 10 11 ...
 $ dist : num  2 10 4 22 16 10 18 26 34 17 ...
> data.df <- cars
```

You can use `lapply`:

```
> data.df <- data.frame(lapply(data.df, factor))
```

Or a `for` statement:

```
> for(i in 1:ncol(data.df)) data.df[,i] <- as.factor(data.df[,i])
```

In either case, you end up with what you want:

```
> str(data.df)
'data.frame':   50 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ speed: Factor w/ 19 levels "4","7","8","9",..: 1 1 2 2 3 4 5 5 5 6 ...
 $ dist : Factor w/ 35 levels "2","4","10","14",..: 1 3 2 9 5 3 7 11 14 6 ...
```

Comment: Shane,

This is exactly the basic function I needed. Sorry I don't have enough reputation points to upvote it :-(

Comment: @briandk: Good to hear!  At some point, just accept it so the community knows it answers your question.  :)

Answer (score 5):

I found an alternative solution in the `plyr` package:

```
# load the package and data
> library(plyr)
> data.df <- cars
```

Use the colwise function:

```
> data.df <- colwise(factor)(data.df)
> str(data.df)
'data.frame':   50 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ speed: Factor w/ 19 levels "4","7","8","9",..: 1 1 2 2 3 4 5 5 5 6 ...
 $ dist : Factor w/ 35 levels "2","4","10","14",..: 1 3 2 9 5 3 7 11 14 6 ...
```

Incidentally, if you look inside the colwise function, it just uses `lapply`:

```
df <- as.data.frame(lapply(filtered, .fun, ...))
```

Comment: @Shane: I wish I could "accept" this one too, since it combines your lapply suggestion with some powerful features from the plyr package.