# Change datatype of multiple columns in dataframe in R

Tags: r, type-conversion

I have the following dataframe:

```
str(dat2)
data.frame: 29081 obs. of 105 variables:
$ id: int 20 34 46 109 158....
$ reddit_id: chr "t1_cnas90f" "t1_cnas90t" "t1_cnas90g"....
$ subreddit_id: chr "t5_cnas90f" "t5_cnas90t" "t5_cnas90g"....
$ link_id: chr "t3_c2qy171" "t3_c2qy172" "t3_c2qy17f"....
$ created_utc: chr "2015-01-01" "2015-01-01" "2015-01-01"....
$ ups: int 3 1 0 1 2....
...
```

How can i change the **datatype** of *reddit_id*, *subreddit_id* and *link_id* from character to factor? I know how to do it one column by column, but as this is tedious work, i am searching for a faster way to do it.

I have tried the following, without success:

```
dat2[2:4] <- data.frame(lapply(dat2[2:4], factor))
```

From [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1489247/6093852). Its end up giving me an error message: *invalid "length" argument*

Another approach was to do it this way:

```
dat2 <- as.factor(data.frame(dat2$reddit_id, dat2$subreddit_id, dat2$link_id))
```

Result: Error in sort.list(y): "x" must be atomic for "sort.

After reading the error i also tried it the other way around:

```
dat2 <- data.frame(as.factor(dat2$reddit_id, dat2$subreddit_id, dat2$link_id))
```

Also without success

If some information are missing, I am sorry. I am a newbie to R and Stackoverflow...Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: Try this: `dat2[,2:4] <- lapply(dat2[,2:4], factor)`

Comment: It worked. Thank you!

Comment: you can also use `unclass` on them

Comment: @Imo that still shows the same error the OP got

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

library("tidyverse")

```
data %>% 
  mutate_at(.vars = vars(reddit_id, subreddit_id, link_id)), 
            .fun = factor)
```

To take advantage of partial matching, use

```
data %>% 
  mutate_at(.vars = vars(contains("reddit"), link_id), 
            .fun = factor)
```